How do you insert a record into a postgres database with kotlin exposed?
I keep getting this error trying to insert a record into postgres using exposed v0.53.0
WARN  Exposed - Transaction attempt #2 failed: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "benefit_id" of relation "benefit" violates not-null constraint

This is my table
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.kotlin.datetime.date

    object BenefitTable: Table() {
        val benefit_id = integer("benefit_id").autoIncrement()
        override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(benefit_id)
        val title = varchar("title", 200)
        val description = varchar("description", 200)
        val status = varchar("status", 200)
        val start_date = date("start_date")
        val end_date = date("end_date")
    }

This is my repository method
fun upsertBenefit(benefit: Benefit): Benefit {
        return transaction {
            if (benefit.benefitId == null) {
                val insertedId = BenefitTable.insert {
                    it[title] = benefit.title
                    it[description] = benefit.description
                    it[status] = benefit.status
                    it[start_date] = benefit.startDate
                    it[end_date] = benefit.endDate
                } get BenefitTable.benefit_id
                val insertedRow = BenefitTable.selectAll().where { BenefitTable.benefit_id eq insertedId }.single()
                mapBenefitRow(insertedRow)
            } else {
                val benefitId = benefit.benefitId!!
                BenefitTable.update({ BenefitTable.benefit_id eq benefitId }) {
                    it[title] = benefit.title
                    it[description] = benefit.description
                    it[status] = benefit.status
                    it[start_date] = benefit.startDate
                    it[end_date] = benefit.endDate
                }
                val updatedRow = BenefitTable.selectAll().where { BenefitTable.benefit_id eq benefitId }.single()
                mapBenefitRow(updatedRow)
            }
        }
    }

How do I get exposed to generate an id on insert?
I get the same error using the upsert method.
fun upsertBenefit(benefit: Benefit): Benefit {
        return transaction {
            val insertedId = BenefitTable.upsert {
                it[title] = benefit.title
                it[description] = benefit.description
                it[status] = benefit.status
                it[start_date] = benefit.startDate
                it[end_date] = benefit.endDate
            } get BenefitTable.benefit_id
            val insertedRow = BenefitTable.selectAll().where { BenefitTable.benefit_id eq insertedId }.single()
            mapBenefitRow(insertedRow)
        }
    }

org.jetbrains.exposed.exceptions.ExposedSQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "benefit_id" of relation "benefit" violates not-null constraint

We're already using this database with a spring boot application that is using JOOQ. JOOQ can handle basic crud operations without issue so it doesn't seem to be an issue with our postgres setup.

you need to add .entityId() after .autoIncrement()
val benefit_id = integer("benefit_id").autoIncrement().entityId()

